# Spring Security + JSF 2.0 + Primefaces + Hibernate configuration

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, spring-security

I need to configure a project with Spring Security + JSF 2.0 + Primefaces + Hibernate. I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1. To put the required jars inside the /WEB-INF/lib folder and reference them from Project > Properties > Libraries is the best choice? Another issue is what are the real necessary jars to this web app work? Every tutorial i've read tells me a diferente one.

Comment: When you use Properties -> Libraries, the jars are automatically added to classpath. you don't have to include them in WEB-INF/lib. Just put them in a folder outside the project, and I suggest you use relative path to reference them.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use maven..it is a good project management tool...i personally use it for dependency management....you can refer this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/)...